# What's wrong with my Ruby method? It should return HTML tags

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a method, based on a RSpec test specification, that returns a couple of valid HTML tags. This is the RSpec:

```
describe "link_to" do
  it "should return a valid link for Yahoo" do
    link_to("Yahoo", "http://www.yahoo.com").should eq("<a href='http://www.yaho.com'>Yahoo</a>")
 end
   it "should return a valid link for Google" do
     link_to("Google", "http://www.google.com").should eq("<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>")
  end
end
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
def link_to(address1, address2, text1, text2)
  "<a href=#{address1}>#{text1}</a>"
  "<a href=#{address2}>#{text2}</a>"
end

p link_to("http://www.yahoo.com", "'http://www.google.com'", "Yahoo", "Google")
```

And I get this error:

> ArgumentError
>
> wrong number of arguments (2 for 4)

Comment: What's the point of your overwriting of existing helper `link_to`? The original one can return the same and much better.

Comment: @BillyChan, Ruby doesn't have an existing `link_to` method.

Comment: @BillyChan Who says he's using Rails?

Comment: Guys, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

The error is clear, you define the method with 4 arguments

```
link_to(address1, address2, text1, text2)
```

But call it with 2:

```
link_to("Yahoo", "http://www.yahoo.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

In the RSpec you're calling `link_to` with 2 arguments, whereas it takes 4.

```
link_to("Google", "http://www.google.com")
           ^1               ^2             ^3?,  ^4?
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec, the `link_to` method takes 2 arguments:

```
link_to("Yahoo", "http://www.yahoo.com") # <- 2 arguments
```

The first argument is the link text (`"Yahoo"`), the second argument is the address (`"http://www.yahoo.com"`).

Your method currently takes 4 arguments (that's why you get an `ArgumentError`):

```
def link_to(address1, address2, text1, text2)
  # ...
end
```

Instead, your method signature should look like this (note the argument order, link text comes first):

```
def link_to(text, address)
  # ...
end
```

After fixing this, your spec fails with:

```
expected: "<a href='http://www.yaho.com'>Yahoo</a>"
     got: nil
```

No more `ArgumentError`, that's great. Let's add your implementation (just one line because it should not return 2 lines at once):

```
def link_to(text, address)
  "<a href=#{address}>#{text}</a>"
end
```

Still failing, but I think you can sort it out :-)

```
expected: "<a href='http://www.yaho.com'>Yahoo</a>"
     got: "<a href=http://www.yahoo.com>Yahoo</a>"
```